# What would I have to pay by sending data across region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

The problem is that I want to use lambda + S3 + SNS to do some Event-driven processing. But I have to keep data in EU(Frankfurt) region. unfortuately there is no lambda service available in this region.

So the possible solution would be

```
1) S3(EU Frankfurt region) --> Lambda(other region) --> S3(EU Frankfurt region)
```

Does this feasible? Does this transferring data across the region cost extra money?

```
2) is there any other lambda comparable service which could be a substitution of this solution?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data transfer is for Lambda is billed the same way as it is billed for EC2.

Lambda running in eu-west-1:
Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Another AWS Region $0.02 per GB

S3 in eu-central-1:
Data Transfer OUT From Amazon S3 To Another AWS Region  $0.02 per GB